# Add fee to WooCommerce checkout if order below X excluding VAT

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

How do I add an administration fee of 105 DKK (including VAT) on all orders below 2000 DK (excluding VAT)?

So if someone orders for less than 2000 DKK excluding VAT, I want them to pay a surcharge named Administrative Fee. This is in WooCommerce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code to add fee depending upon your cart total amount.

```
/**
 * Add custom fee to checkout section
 */
function woo_add_cart_fee() {
    global $woocommerce;
    if ( $woocommerce->cart->total <= 2000 ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( __( 'Administrative Fee' ), 105 , true, 'standard'); //Add tax on 105
        //$woocommerce->cart->add_fee( __( 'Administrative Fee' ), 105 , false); // no tax on 105
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee' );
```

You can change the price comparing condition based on your requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For some reason this adds the fee always, even if the order is above 2000? How do you make it so that the fee is ONLY added if the order is less than the 2000.

Comment: @eMikkelsen, Please check your cart total and if it is above 2000 put a else condition as per this:
else {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( __( 'Administrative Fee' ), 0 , true, 'standard');     }